# Magento - Custom Module Nested Router Frontname

Tags: magento, module, url-routing

I have setup a custom module in my magento store (CE-1.9.0.0) with the following in my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Custom>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Custom>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custom>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>our-work/digital-work</frontName>
                </args>
            </custom>
        </routers>
        etc...
```

I know that when I have setup custom modules before the frontname works when it is a single string (i.e if I wanted to use just `digital-work` this works, just not when I have a nested string in place as in `our-work/digital-work` - this results in a page not found.

I am new to routers and magento so I presume I have misinterpreted what is possible in the `<frontName>` Is it possible to have a nested frontname?

Answer (score 0):

The frontName is not the url, instead it represents only the first part of it!
Usually a magento action url looks like
domain.com/frontName/controllerName/action
where frontName is the name specified in the config.xml, controllerNameController.php is the controller having the function actionAction
[Explained Here](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/)

So frontName is the part that maps to your module, for example you might have a module Company_Custom but you want don't want to have urls as "company_custom/features/list", instead you want something like "custom/features/list" in this case you should have:

```
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>custom</frontName>
                </args>
```

You can use URL rewrite from Admin in order to map a custom url to the real url